# Populate back multipart/form data

Tags: jsp, el

I created a small JSP to take input from user and also upload an Image file.
Here is the form code of that JSP:

```
<form action="DBController" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Product Code<input type="text" name="productCode" value="${productCode}" />
    Upload Image<input type="file" name="image" value="${image}" />
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="addProductToDB">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now when I am forwarding request back to this JSP form fields (productCode) are not getting populated.
Can anyone please tell me why?

Comment: You cannot populate `type='file'` inputs programmatically.  Its a security feature of browsers.

Comment: okay even if I ignore populating file, I am not able to populate Product Code. I explicitly have to write: request.setAttribute("productCode",value); in the servlet so as to populate it here. Isn't there anyway to take it directly from multipart/form?

Comment: When you forward you lose the original request params, so that's why you have to do `request.setAttribute("productCode",value)` in the servlet: that's normal. Well, maybe not: you might could use `${params.productCode}` if it wasn't `multipart/form-data` but that won't work with `multipart/form-data` for the same reason `request.getParameter()` doesn't work with `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation developerwjk :)